# Where'd my rep go?

Tags: discussion, cleanup, deleted-questions

This is just a heads up post that I did a little bit of house cleaning today. A few people might notice <strike>as it will mean a pretty big hit to their rep.</strike> The most affected people are going to be [Affable Geek](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/1039/affable-geek) and [yours truly](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/users/30/caleb), <strike>loosing a couple hundred each</strike>, with a few other people taking smaller hits. Ironically, several people will get an increase out of this as some of their highly downvoted content has been removed -- which was the my aim.

What I did is sort through some of the most down-voted questions for ones that had been closed for a significant amount of time (most of them were '11, a few from this spring), that did not show any hope of being re-opened and permanently deleted them. I did not remove anything recent or that the community had shown any interest in trying to fix up. I tried not to take down anything with re-open votes or comments on how it could possibly be improved. All the questions were -5 or deeper in the hole. For reference:[1](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/8257/30), [2](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/4959/30), [3](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6635/30), [4](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/6804/30), [5](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2676/30), [6](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7670/30), [7](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/7668/30).

There were a few upvoted answers even on these bad questions. I put several hours at least into my own answers. However even among the people that took the time to answer, there seemed to be a sentiment that these were not well thought out questions that should characterize a site for experts, we only answered out of a duty to set the record straight so to speak.

If anyone has specific concerns about these, feel to bring them up. If you find anything that stood a chance of being re-opened I'd be happy to review it. Otherwise I think it's for the best that content the community clearly didn't appreciate shouldn't hang around clogging the tubes.

**Edit:** Nobody is loosing more than a few pence of rep at all. Apparently since the posts in question were older than 90 days and had 3+ upvotes, and the deleted post was the question not the answer directly, nobody is really affected by this in terms of rep.

Comment: Answers from 2011 shouldn't be affected to much, if they are older than 90 days and have more than 3 upvotes, the reputation is kept even if the question is deleted.

Comment: @MadScientist: I didn't now that. Almost everything in question fits those conditions. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: The 1..7 links are 404s, for reference.

Comment: @Kaz Dragon: They will be visible to you when you hit [2000](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/privileges/moderator-tools) in the beta period.

Comment: I'm not usually one to ask about downvotes, but the entire reason I posted this was because I was acting on behalf of the community and wanted to be transparent about what was going on. If anybody has concerns, I'd be happy to hear them as answers. I'm listening but I don't know how to interpret a drive-by downvote on this post.

Comment: I appreciate the heads up :)  Admittedly, I was kind of hoping for a "reversal" badge on some of those.  I would love to get a +20 answer on a -5 question some time...

Comment: Ahh Finally!! I had been lobbying to get that number 7 delete for such a long time.

Comment: Those were truly awful questions. I don't mind the hit to rep at all if it means getting those stinkers off the site. Thanks for the heads-up. "Why sheep and not cats..." Seriously.

Comment: @DavidStratton: As hard as my job is sometimes I'm profoundly grateful that the correct analogy for it is that of a shepherd and not a cat-wrangler.

Comment: I keep seeing "Where'd my _repo_ go?"

Comment: @JustinY: You've been programming too long :) I almost wrote this out as "reputation" but after reading it over decided that sounded awkward in another way.

Answer (score 2):

On https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6635/was-george-w-bush-a-prophet, I wonder if we could edit that into a decent question (with the extant answer) by changing it to:

"What differentiates a prophet from any person who 'hears from God'?"

As an example, George W. Bush...

Comment: I'm sure it COULD be done. The trouble is nobody was making a move to do it. I think you have the rep to cast undelete votes and I'd be happy to back you up to make that happen if somebody is going to edit it and try to get it re-opened. Closed questions will not sit around indefinitely.

Comment: @Caleb: ...unless they are duplicates.

Comment: When I cast an undelete vote, it says the moderator has deleted it.  My real question is, do you think its worth salvaging, with that rewording...

Comment: @AffableGeek I think it might be -- somebody just has to try and then put reopening it to vote. Knock yourself out :)

Comment: @JonEricson: True, I missed that in my list but you are correct, duplicates stick around forever. They serve a purpose that _Not Constructive_, _Off Topic_, and _Not a Real Question_ closes do not.

Comment: @Caleb One other minor request - could you make deletions closer to the beginning of a day rather than right at the end?  It's a minor quibble, but for example, I had 50 points over the cap that day, which would have offset the loss - but because its time-based, it didn't offset.  That said, I realize I'm sounding like a rep-grubber :) so it really isn't that big a deal...

Comment: @AffableGeek: I think it's going to need more than a title fix (although that's obviously the first step). Also you would want to cast a re-open vote yourself and then maybe mention in chat or elsewhere to lobby for a few more votes. If it doesn't get re-open votes and some upvotes, it's going to die the second death for which there is no resurrection.